# Fixing fake rotation

Tags: snapping

I've got a model, which after importing from CAD has wrong rotation, but in blender it has rotation equal 0,0,0 . I need to correct "visual rotation" to correct model rotation. [image]

Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem, because all the models in this import have wrong "visual rotation". 
Thanks for future advices.

Comment: Did you try to **change the import option** when importing CAD files? There should be some option on the* left hand side bottom*.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that, set snapping on with these setting:

[image]

Then create an empty and move it on the face on the nut:

[image]

The empty now has the same orientation as the nut.

Parent the nut to the empty: select the nut then shift select the empty and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Now select the empty and remove its rotation using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

[image]

The nut is well oriented.

Last steps, clear parent from the nut <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> with keep transforms and apply its rotation <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then rotation.

Note: if several objects have the same fake rotation, you can use the same process parenting them all to the empty.

Comment: Works great! Thanks ! :D